# Doctrine ManyToOne with information missing in this object

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I try to get a zf2 doctrine2 projekt up and running with a very old database (and that cannot be changed a lot, because it's serving an old php project).

I have a table "web" with:

- **webID**
- pID
- name
- ...

A Table "p_news_category" with:

- **id**
- **pID**
- **webID**
- name
- ...

A Table "news" with:

- **newsID**
- **webID**
- category
- title
- ...

(bold == primary)

As you can see, the news doesn't have the info for the "pID" (project id), but the category tables needs it, because it's a primary key.

I now tried (inside my news Entity)

```
/**
 * @var \Mobil\Entity\Web
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mobil\Entity\Web")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="webID", referencedColumnName="webID")
 * })
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $webid;

/**
 * @var \Mobil\Entity\PNewsCategory
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mobil\Entity\PNewsCategory")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category", referencedColumnName="id"),
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="webID", referencedColumnName="webID")
 * })
 */
private $category;
```

But: **Missing value for primary key pid on Mobil\Entity\PNewsCategory**

How can I write the @ORM\JoinColumn for the pID?

Answer (score 0):

You have the category already in your news entity, so you need to define a bidirectional relationship between news and news_category with news as the owning side and news_category as the inverse side.

### UPDATE:

If the primary key from category is `id`, then it should work. As I understand from your question `pId` is the key pointing to a `Project`, so in the `Category` entity it is a foreign key, not a primary key.

If you want to make the question more clear, please show all your entities with their key definitions.

Comment: Thats exactly what my code should do isn't it?
But, it's not working because something like

    @ORM\JoinColumn(name="webID.pID", referencedColumnName="pID")

is missing.

Comment: As I wrote in the question: (bold == primary)

The primary from PNewsCategory is id, pID and webID - and I cannot change that. My only problem is, that my news does not know about her project (directly), it needs his "webid" relation to know the pID.

Comment: @Kipperlenny Okay, I hear you. But is `id` in `p_news_category` at least unique or not?

Comment: no, only "id, pID, webID" together are unique - these database is 13 years old and cannot be changed (because it serves another running project from this customer). and the id is a varchar btw. not important here, but shows the problem even more :D

Comment: You try to define ManyToOne from news (many) to category (one). but if a category is specified by `id + pID + webID`  how can you link a single category to news with only `webID + category` ?